# How to toggle <a> on click on and off with two <a>

Tags: jquery

Hello I have two `<a></a>` and how to do this?

If I press upvote the upvote will add class `upvote_color` and when I click it again it will remove `upvote_color`. then same on downvote.

But when the `upvote` is active and I will click `downvote`, the `upvote` will become `default_color` and vice versa. Like a reddit upvote and downvote.

[image: This is my [image sample][1]]

HTML

```
<a class="upvote default_color" data-product_id="12" href="#"> <!-- change to from default_color to upvote_color -->
    <span class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></span>
</a> 
<a class="downvote default_color" data-product_id="12" href="#"> <!-- change to from default_color to downvote_color-->
    <span class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></span></a>
</p>
```

JQUERY (tried so far but my head hurts cant figure it out)

```
$(".upvote").click( function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var product_id = $(this).data('product_id');
        var a = $(this);
        $(this).toggleClass( function(){
            // $( this ).attr('style','left: 300px');
            console.log($(this));

            if(a.is('.upvote_color')) {
                a.removeClass('upvote_color');
            } else {
                a.addClass('upvote_color');
            }
        });
});
```

**EDIT**

all I want is like reddit style, but don't know that much logic on jquery.

1. if he upvote already then click downvote, the upvote become white and downvote become red. and vice versa
2. if he upvote already then click again the upvote, the upvote become white.
   and vice versa.
3. there should be if else cause I will ajax it on my PHP side.

**EDIT2:**

HTML

```
<div class="pull-right">
    <a class="vote upvote" data-product_id="12" href="#">
        <span class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></span>
    </a> 
    <span class="like_count">100</span>
    <a class="vote downvote" data-product_id="12" href="#">
        <span class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></span>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="pull-right">
    <a class="vote upvote" data-product_id="13" href="#">
        <span class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></span>
    </a> 
    <span class="like_count">100</span>
    <a class="vote downvote" data-product_id="13" href="#">
        <span class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$('.vote').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).siblings('a.vote').removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');   
    var product_id = $(this).data('product_id');
    if( !$(this).hasClass('active')){
        // alert(product_id + ' :unvote');
        $.get("http://localhost/stud/products/unvote", {product_id: product_id}).done( function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });
    } else {
        if( $(this).hasClass('upvote')){
            // alert(product_id + ' :upvote');
            $.get("http://localhost/stud/products/upvote", {product_id: product_id}).done( function(data){
                console.log(data);
            });
        } else {
            // alert(product_id + ' :downvote');
            $.get("http://localhost/stud/products/downvote", {product_id: product_id}).done( function(data){
                console.log(data);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it simply with something looks like this.(seems to be you using jQuery)

```
$("a.upvote").click( function(e){
    e.preventDefault();      
    $(this).toggleClass('upvote_color');
});
```

More information you can find it here: http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

http://jsfiddle.net/8rrctstf/11/

//I may use this one to get like count

```
var likeCount =  $(this).siblings('.like_count');
var count = parseInt(likeCount.text());
//check if it is number
if(count !== 'NaN'){
    //doing calculation and set it back
    likeCount.text(count);
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8rrctstf/6/ build in Terence solution's. Doing a bit refactor. So it is usually add active class to button to toggle color (sorry too low reputation point so can't comment on your answer @Terence)

Comment: how to determine it if it is downvote or upvote? maybe just alert 1 if upvote, 0 if he unvoted/undownvoted, -1 if downvote

Comment: it's not working... try upvote on 1st set then upvote on 2nd set then downvote on 3rd set

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8rrctstf/11/ just check class it has. Not the best solution but it works for moment (update for multi select).

Comment: when you upvote on other, the they should not remove and stays upvote. try upvote on first set then upvote on 2nd set, the first set vote removed...

Comment: did you try this one? the new version should handle multi select and alert actions (upvote, downvote, unvote) 
jsfiddle.net/8rrctstf/11

Comment: can you check new edit2, I want to increment the `<span class="like_count">100</span>` how to find it?

Answer (score 1):

Building on Tran's answer, you should probably check whether the button has the voted color set before toggling the class (to prevent both button's color from being set on the first vote).

```
$('.upvote').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('default_color voted_color');
    if ($('.downvote').hasClass('voted_color')) {
        $('.downvote').toggleClass('default_color voted_color');
    }
});
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8rrctstf/4/).

The jQuery [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) function adds or removes the classes based on whether the element has them or not.
I'm sure this jQuery can be made much more efficient though.

Comment: what if I have 3 class, `upvote_color`, `downvote_color`, `default_color`

Comment: had one problem, it should be unique. when I implemented it other will affect too. look here http://jsfiddle.net/8rrctstf/7/

Comment: @StormSpirit It looks like Tran has fixed the issue of voting only affecting each pair by using the sibling selector.

Answer (score 0):

Toggle Function must be return;

```
$(".upvote").click( function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var product_id = $(this).data('product_id');
            var a = $(this);
            $(this).toggleClass( function(){
                // $( this ).attr('style','left: 300px');
                console.log($(this));

                if(a.is('.upvote_color')) {
                    a.removeClass('upvote_color');
                    return '';
                } else {
                    a.addClass('upvote_color');
                    return '';
                }
            });
    });
```